# Fifty Migration Candidates from ELU > ELL

Tags: discussion, migration, closed-questions

Some weeks ago now, Grace asked that we please assemble a list of candidate ELU-to-ELL questions instead of flagging them.

I compiled such a list based on people’s nominations, but it is a bit hard to find in [this posting](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3772/2085).

So here is that list of migration nominees again, nearly all of which are closed on ELU:

- [can “love” be used in place of “like”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/89912)
- [Can “with” be replaced by “to” after verbs?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/103547)
- [“Children playing” or “Playing children”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/100526)
- [Contact us “on” or “at”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/103717)
- [Correct use of ‘blond’](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/101062)
- [Difference between “anyone” and “everyone”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/103930)
- [Difference between “hereafter” and “thereafter”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/102586)
- [Difference between “they aren’t” and “they couldn’t”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/103249)
- [English Grammar](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/88342)
- [“Event is raised when maintenance occurs or scheduled” vs. “or is scheduled”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/102538)
- [Feel and Feeling](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/102720)
- [General advice on learning English](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/100403)
- [Grammatically incorrect sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/103607)
- [How to ask “Where are you going?” when event already passed?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/103818)
- [How to write “only for female” on jeans tag](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/33880)
- [“I don’t know nothing” vs “I don’t know anything”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/78759)
- [Is a “perfect participle” right?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/92058)
- [Is “he should be seventeen” correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/104982)
- [Is it right to say “my sandals are broken”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/77532)
- [Is “stuff” a plural word?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/1234)
- [Is the “one's” and “their” used correctly?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/103793)
- [Is the phrase “… or I'm mistaken” correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/96296)
- [“Is there anything else we could/will have done?”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/50715)
- [Is this sentence correct in grammar and does it even make sense](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/77745)
- [Is word ‘request’ by itself as polite form of asking for something?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/103641)
- [Length of Answer!](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/104197)
- [“Match manual” or “match manually”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/104781)
- [Meaning of “long gone”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/77756)
- [Meaning of the phrase “I am all ears”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/103074)
- [“More” vs. “more than”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/101567)
- [Most is vs most are](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/93304)
- [“Mr. Dill works ________ a big library”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/105165)
- [“One should warn” vs. “it should warn”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/73296)
- [“Prices vary state to state” vs. “prices vary from state to state”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/83276)
- [Proper use of “the”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/102577)
- [“Roll” vs. “roll up”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/104018)
- [Talking “on behalf of Iranians” or “instead of Iranians”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/102592)
- [Usage of “Make Sense”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/103459)
- [Usage of “one other” and “another one”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/87427)
- [Using contractions like “I'm” in text](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/101489)
- [What does “an unwillingness of a privileged white author to abandon his frame” mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/104983)
- [What does “long enough to” mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/101454)
- [what does “the powers that be have to really mean it for the work to matter” mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/77652)
- [What is wrong with this sentence? and the correction if necessary](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/104647)
- [What’s the difference between order and bill?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/103629)
- [“Where am I?” vs. “Where I am?”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/93004)
- [Which phrase is more natural to a native speaker?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/100001)
- [Why in shops they put “B sold here” instead of “B sells here”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/104352)
- [Why “the” in “Three Men in a Boat (To Say Nothing of the Dog)”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/93570)
- [Word order: “achieved solution” vs. “solution achieved”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/103130)

Comment: Grace would make better to operate for having a new moderator here rather than to propose unacceptable (mass)migration of questions. ELL is not the trash of ELU, though.

Comment: Yes, I think they should be moved over here. At the very least, the ones which were closed without satisfactory answers should be migrated.

Comment: We should migrate them, but I think perhaps we should avoid migrating them *all at once*. If you do that, you run the risk of flooding ELL with new questions that will then go unanswered and will swamp other questions. If we begin the process of migrating them, say, a handful a day, we'll be able to add activity to ELL without potentially swamping the active answerers we have on this forum and ending up with large numbers of "dead questions" on ELL.

Comment: Is there a meta question that discusses WHY ELL + ELU both need to exist? Why the split?

Comment: @WarrenP No, I don’t there is such a meta question. You can look over at [the ELL Area51 site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners), where it calls it “a site for speakers of other languages learning English”. Don’t miss [the definition section](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665?phase=definition).

Comment: I posted one. I think ELU already covers ELL topics.